# openlayers3 : ol.style.Icon in vectorContext.setStyle can not work?

Tags: openlayers-3

This example shows how to use postcompose and vectorContext to animate features:

http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-animation.html

I try to replace the style in these lines:

```
var style = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: radius,
        snapToPixel: false,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, ' + opacity + ')',
            width: 0.25 + opacity
        })
    })
});

vectorContext.setStyle(style);
```

when I replace the style to an img style, like this:

```
var style = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(({
        src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/data/icon.png'
    }))
});
```

it's not working and throws an error: Cannot read property '0' of null

Is it a bug? Or how can I use img style about it?

Comment: I don't find any error in your code; everything should work properly. Can you provide a living example, so that we can see what is happening?

Comment: this is a example:  https://jsfiddle.net/codingmiao/9gou6rwL/6/  ,I just change the style on line 53(the original example is http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-animation.html  ),the function "animate" can't work...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an image instead of a normal Point, you don't need to change the style into the animate function.

You can add the desired style into the vector layer this way:

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: source,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon(({
            src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/data/icon.png'
        }))
    })
});
```

I edited your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9gou6rwL/8/) without any style for the vectorContext. If you want to get some animation, like in the Openlayers Site example, you only have to add the old styling by uncommenting it in the jsfiddle code.

Comment: Thanks,I want to do an animation: a red point moving along the line,like this: https://jsfiddle.net/codingmiao/9gou6rwL/9/  ,and replace the red point to an image style,but I failed..

Comment: What you wanted was not explicitly described in your question, that's why I encourage you to edit it so that everyone can understand what you mean. The jsfiddle example that you added in the comment to your question was fairly misleading as well. However, here you can find an example of point with custom icon in an animation: https://jsfiddle.net/m0wj9mL2/1/

Comment: I found out why it does not work: ol.style.Icon is used directly in the "vectorContext.drawFeature", but not in other places is ahead of the rendering.
For example, to change line 69 of your example to "features: [routeFeature1]", it will not work